# How do i add the plugin to other project which is saved in my local maven repository (in "~/.m2/repository")

Tags: maven, gradle, plugins

This is my build.gradle file which publishes the resulting artifact to local maven repository (in "~/.m2/repository").

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'application'
}
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'xyz'
            artifactId = 'greeting'
            version = '1.1.1'
        }
    }
}

mainClassName = 'xyz.Greeting'
```

And this is the build.gradle file where i am trying to use the repository

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'xyz',
                name: 'greeting',
                version: '1.1.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

apply plugins : 'xyz.greeting'

mainClassName = 'xy.HelloWorld'
```

I am getting

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'hello-world3'.

> Could not set unknown property 'plugins' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.

as an error message

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo. Changing `apply plugins: 'xyz.greeting'` to `apply plugin: 'xyz.greeting'` might solve your problem.